# How to configure WCF to use HTTP with Client Certificate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, ssl, transport

How to configure WCF to use HTTP (without ssl) with Client Certificate?

On the service side, I tried the below:

```
<bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="binding1">
                    <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"></transport>
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings
```

But it complains that:

```
Certificate-based client authentication is not supported in TransportCredentialOnly security mode. Select the Transport security mode.
```

Thanks,

Comment: And what happens when you set it as `Transport` ?

Comment: Transport means it would require SSL and HTTPS Address which is not what I want. I'd just need to test the Client Certificates working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I fully understand your question.

If you want to configure the security on you binding (basicHttpBinding) to use a client certificate (to authenticate the client) the only way to do this on http as far as I know is to use message security, you can find an example in the [wcf samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751503%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

As stated by the resulting exception and also [on a Distributed Services Support Team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/distributedservices/archive/2010/05/13/wcf-and-intermediate-devices.aspx):

> Note: With the TransportCredentialOnly mode, you cannot use Certificate-based client authentication:
>    Certificate-based client authentication is not supported in TransportCredentialOnly security mode.

Answer (score 0):

What i understand from your question is you want to use your custom certificate that's hasn't been issued by CA(certificate Authority).

In such case you need to install the same on Server and in case if you are using in .NET they the same also need to be attached with your website in IIS.

Hope this works

Comment: that's not correct nor was it relevant to my question. FYI, in terms of which certificate should be installed where. Root CA should be installed on all involved servers (Service and Client) but the Client Certificate would only need to be installed on the Client machine.